# Google map api in Places library error b is not a function

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-apps-script

I am trying to add google map api to my project I following an instruction on document but I am getting this error

> b is not the function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2h0m.png)

I read a document on function nearbySearch() it take at least one parmater and another on can be callback or others i tried add them but still Im getting this error.
here is my code

```
 var map;
    var lat = 51.23916571;
    var lng = -0.586997652;

    function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: pyrmont,
            zoom: 17,

        });
        // Create the places service.
        const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
     
        var request = {
                location: pyrmont,
                radius: '1000',
                type: ['gym']
            };
        // Perform a nearby search.

        service.nearbySearch(request)
        console.log(service)
    }
```

Did I write something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **required** callback function.

See the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search-pagination).

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests):

> `service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);`
> `service.nearbySearch(request, callback);`
> This method takes a request with the following fields:
>
> - Either of:
>   ++ **`bounds`**, which must be a google.maps.LatLngBounds object defining the rectangular search area; or
>   ++ **a `location` and a `radius`**; the former takes a `google.maps.LatLng` object, and the latter takes a simple integer, representing the circle's radius in meters. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters. Note that when `rankBy` is set to `DISTANCE`, you must specify a `location` but you cannot specify a `radius` or `bounds`.

<snip - removing optional parameters>

> `type` — Restricts the results to places matching the specified type. Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored). See the list of supported types.
> **You must also pass a callback method to nearbySearch(), to handle the results object and google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus response.**

Example from the documentation:

```
var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    type: ['restaurant']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/unqr7zxb/1/)

[image: screenshot of working map]

**working code snippet (with your request):**

```js
var map;
var lat = 51.23916571;
var lng = -0.586997652;
var bounds;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 17,

  });
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  // Create the places service.
  const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '1000',
    type: ['gym']
  };
  // Perform a nearby search.
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log("results.length=" + results.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var marker = createMarker(results[i]);
      bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    // display the place "name" and "place_id" in the infowindow.
    infowindow.setContent(place.name + "<br>" + place.place_id);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  return marker;
}
```

```css
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 4;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Place Search Pagination</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly&channel=2" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```